". . .this lot will strip the table bare…" What is this type of phrase called in English?
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 25)

At lunch. Martin and William are choristers visiting Martin's parents


Martin saves him by dropping the second two slices he takes onto William's plate, and proceeds to take two servings of everything, one for William, then one for himself; roast potatoes, mashed potatoes, cauliflower cheese, peas, carrots and gravy - the sort of meal William would have expected at Christmas or a special Sunday lunch.
'What a sweet boy you are,' Says Mr Mussey to Martin, rubbing his head. 'Do you see that, darling? He's actually thinking of someone else.'
'Just as well.' Mrs Mussey piles carrots onto her plate. 'If you don't dig in quick here, William dear, this lot will strip the table bare before you've located your cutlery.'

I understand the meaning of 'strip the table bare', but I'm not sure  if it used literally or figuratively.  Does it mean 'the others will have scoffed all the food before you have located your cutlery,'?
a) Is it meant as a warning or as a joke ?
b) Does this type of phrase "strip the table bare" have a name in English?

Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Who downvoted this question?

Not I, but presumably someone thought the answer was obvious!

Well, three people evidently agreed with my comment that the answer was obvious - and, as I said, you had found it for yourself!

I don't criticise your comment, on the contrary. Maybe it's obvious for you and others. But get me right, it's NOT obvious for a non-native speaker, quite the contrary! For instance Oxford has this: " strip [transitive] to remove all the things from a place and leave it empty
strip something (out) We had to strip out all the old wiring and start again.
strip something + adj. Thieves had stripped the house bare." So you see, for a non-native speaker its meaning there is not in the least obvious, it is highly questionable and debatable, actually!

As a non-native speaker you are possibly able to guess its meaning right but you aren't able to know its intended meaning. That's the difference between a native speaker and a non-native speaker in this matter. As an aside: In your second comment you are saying: ". . . presumably someone thought the answer was obvious!" I took that to mean you aren't going along with these thoughts of someone automatically. That was a well-conceived comment in my opinion :)

Our sister site, ELL, is intended for more basic questions a second-language learner say might have. ELU is (or was when established) intended for linguists and those with a reasonable command of English. // 'Strip the table bare' is a hyperbole (they will doubtless leave the tablecloth and cutlery), a faintly humorous way of saying 'wolf everything down' / 'devour all the food', as you guess. One could also argue it's a metaphor (figurative).


I understand the meaning of 'strip the table bare', but I'm not sure if it used literally or figuratively. Does it mean 'the others will have scoffed all the food before you have located your cutlery'?

Yes; as Edwin suggests, it's less a metaphor and more a hyperbole; they will eat a lot very quickly, but not literally eat everything that is on the table in less time than it takes William to find his fork.

a) Is it meant as a warning or as a joke ?

Probably a joke. Since there is already food on William's plate, for Mrs. Mussey's words to be a real warning it would mean there's a real danger that others would steal food from his plate, and that seems unlikely. It's also possible that her words were more general, using "you" to mean "a person, in general," not just William's situation in particular. In that case, there could be a real warning that if someone doesn't serve themself promptly (as Martin did), food will run out before they have a chance. But even that seems most likely a bit of hyperbole, and simply to be a commentary on the others' appetite or manners.

b) Does this type of phrase "strip the table bare" have a name in English?

Well, a phrase with its own set meaning is an idiom, though this isn't a very established one. An exaggeration is hyperbole (or just exaggeration). If you mean, "what do you call a phrase with the form 'verb, object, adjective' in which the verb causes the adjective state to happen to the object..." That's a resultative construction, and the adjective is an object complement.

More specifically, this is an example of a resultative construction. The adjective "bare" expresses the state that the table will be in as a result of the action of the verb (stripping).

@nschneid Thanks; I'll steal that right into my answer
